# Can generic variables be reused?

Tags: java, generics

I was just wondering can a generic variable be reused.  For example if I had a generic class that saves a database model supplied to it:

```
 DataManager<ModelObject1> manager = new DataManager<ModelObject1>();
 ModelObject1 object = new ModelObject1();
 object.setSomeProperty();
 manager.save(object);
```

Could I then reuse that same object to save a different type of model without creating a new generic variable.  How could I do something like this:

```
 manager = null;
 manager = new DataManager<ModelObject2>();
 ModelObject2 object2 = new ModelObject2();
 object2.setSomeProperty();
 manager.save(object2);
```

Comment: Oh, instead of "object", you mean "variable".  No, a variable has a unique type, and the parameters of a generic class are part of the type.

Comment: Why bother?  You won't actually save any memory or anything this way.  There are no benefits at all to reusing a reference like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure, a `DataManager<ModelObject1>()` is actually **exactly the same** as a `DataManager<ModelObject2>()` at creation time so from that perspective there is no reason why it should not be reused - after the correct casting.

However, there are some caveats. If you modify the object to contain a reference to something that is specific to the defining class then things get complicated:

Something like this would mean you cannot re-use the object safely:

```
DataManager<ModelObject1> manager = new DataManager<ModelObject1>();
manager.setObject(new ModelObject1());
```

I would strongly recommend against it without a very good reason however. Perhaps if creating the manager is a very heavy process you could justify reusing them.

This code compiles fine but I would stongly recommend an `ss.clear()` before the cast or an `is.clear()` after or you will end up with a `Set<integer>` containing a `String` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> ss = new HashSet<String> ();
    ss.add("Hello");
    Set<Integer> is = unsecureCast(ss);
}

static Set<Integer> unsecureCast(Set s) {
    return (Set<Integer>) s;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is accepted as it's the complete opposite of what the OP asked about. This is talking about assigning the same instance to a different reference of an incompatible generic type (bad idea). The OP is asking about assigning a new instance of an incompatible generic type to the same reference (also a bad idea and pointless).

Comment: @PaulBellora - I think I agree with you to an extent. However, if you read the question up to (but not including) *How could I do something like this: ...* which is how the question looked when I answered, you may find that I actually answered the question OP originally meant to ask, i.e. *Could I then reuse that same object to save a different type of model?*

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right. I wonder if the typo I fixed on the question was intentional. Others seem to have been similarly confused and edited "object" to "variable".

Answer (score 3):

That would not compile. You can't assign a `DataManager<ModelObject2>` to a variable of type `DataManager<ModelObject1>`, since they're not the same type.